How can I specify and visualize an interaction in a rms cph model without the main effects included, i.e. with column?
I have a time-to-event model (cph or coxph) with an interaction of a binary and a continuous variable. It works with a *, but it does not work with :. Why is that?
library("survival")
library(rms)

data("pbc")
head(pbc)
pbc$sex = as.numeric(pbc$sex=='f')

temp <- subset(pbc, id <= 312, select=c(id:sex, stage)) # baseline
pbc2 <- tmerge(temp, temp, id=id, death = event(time, status)) #set range
pbc2 <- tmerge(pbc2, pbcseq, id=id, ascites = tdc(day, ascites),
             bili = tdc(day, bili), albumin = tdc(day, albumin),
             protime = tdc(day, protime), alk.phos = tdc(day, alk.phos))

d = datadist(pbc2)
options(datadist = 'd') # to facilitate plotting
mod_adj <- cph(Surv(tstart,tstop,death==2) ~ sex + sex : rcs(alk.phos,4)+ albumin  + bili , 
        id = factor(id), x=TRUE,data = pbc2)

Error in if (!length(fname) || !any(fname == zname)) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
The same model runs if I use * instead of :.
With the *, I can visualize it with
wadj = rms::Predict(mod_adj, alk.phos, sex = c(0),conf.type='mean')
ggplot(wadj)
How can this model run with the : interaction only, and how to visualize it?

I think you're confusing the model specification.
The term sex:alk.phos is only the interaction term, while sex * alk.phos expands into sex + alk.phos + sex:alk.phos. Therefore, you cannot predict for sex = 0 if sex is not in the original model

sex can be in the model, but I don't want alk.phos in the model. Do both terms have to be there?  I found that this works
... ~ sex +rcs(alk.phos,3) + sex:rcs(alk.phos,3)+ ...
but again, remove the main effect and it does not:
..~ sex + sex:rcs(alk.phos,3)...
If we always need to have the main effect in the model, what is the interaction formulation with : for at all? Then we can just always use the *.
